# No HDMI output Nvidia 331 driver

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, xrandr, nvidia-prime

I've had a long running battle trying to get dual external monitor outputs from my 14.04 system. One monitor is VGA, the other is HDMI. Specifically, I get no HDMI video signal, but Ubuntu knows I have a monitor connected.

I've installed the Nvidia proprietary 331 driver, but still no output. I now think this is something to do with my Xrandr configuration

Output from `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3520 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS1 connected 1600x900+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1600x900       60.1*+
   1440x900       59.9  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080      60.0* 
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
   1400x900_60.00   60.0  
   1920x1080_60.00   60.0  
HDMI1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080      60.0 +   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1400x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1440x576       50.0  
   1440x576i      50.1  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   1440x480       60.0     59.9  
   1440x480i      60.1     60.1  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1400x900_60.00 (0x2aa)  103.5MHz
        h: width  1400 start 1480 end 1624 total 1848 skew    0 clock   56.0KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  934           clock   60.0Hz
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x2ab)  173.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock   60.0Hz
```

As you can see, the HDMI is connected, but I get no signal to the monitor.

I have the following in my `.xprofile`

```
xrandr --newmode "1400x900_60.00"  103.50  1400 1480 1624 1848  900 903 913 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1400x900_60.00
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

which I would have expected to set up the HDMI monitor correctly. When I run this command

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

I get

```
xrandr: cannot find crtc for output HDMI1
```

Output from command lspci:

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 044f
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 330M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 044f
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: You have hybrid graphics. That is a problem. Look here http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/get-hdmi-working-with-nvidia-optimus-on.html

Comment: Thanks mate. Looks like you have to bin Unity and I don't want to do that. Also seems quite complicated and I'm not sure it's guaranteed to work on a connected TV too, which is part of why I wanted to get this working. Oh well, looks like Windows has scored one over Ubuntu, for this particular point.

Answer (score 0):

Try your cable-connections, it should show connected, HDMI is kind of tricky with it, and Turn on hdmi in monitor settings and apply, say ok when there does appear an image;

And make that default.

Comment: Oh yes I tried different cables. The monitor was detected, but unfortunately no image was shown. But I'm now using another computer, which hopefully I'll have more luck with. Failing that, it's back to Win 10 :(